# how to set breakpoint in gemfile for rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubygems, rubymine, gemfile

I'm currently looking at the guts of [query_report](http://ashrafuzzaman.github.io/query_report/) gem by examining the sample project that comes with it. I was wondering if it is possible to set a breakpoint in rubymine in one of the files in the gem itself?

Answer (score 2):

sure you can.
In the project explorer open the *"External Libraries"*, browse for query_report, open it and open the relevant rb file. there you'll see the source code and be able to set breakpoints.
Just did that In RubyMine EAP Hinoki